# My (simple) code links in g++, doesn't link in clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

This is a very simple drill in Stroustrup's PPP, you create 3 files:

my.h:

```
void print_foo();
void print(int);
```

my.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "my.h"

using namespace std;

void print(int i)
{
    cout << i << '\n';
}

void print_foo()
{
    cout << "Foo" << '\n';
}
```

and use.cpp:

```
#include "my.h"

int main()
{
    print_foo();
    print(7);
}
```

My clang version is `Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0`

This compiles in both clang and g++, but doesn't link in clang. I get this:

```
$ clang my.cpp use.cpp -std=c++14 -o drill8_1
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

Does anyone know why this would be the case? I typed the same command into g++, and I got the correct output.

Thank you :)

Here is the rest of the clang output:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      print(int) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      print(int) in my-82a25e.o
      print_foo() in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in my-82a25e.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in my-82a25e.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in my-82a25e.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in my-82a25e.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in my-82a25e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What symbols are undefined?

Comment: I've edited my post with the undefined symbols.

Comment: Yes, clang++ worked! Should I be using this for all c++ code?

Comment: @EmanuelHartmann Either that, or add `-lc++` to your compile to link with the c++ library.

Comment: That is the same like when you try to call gcc instead of g++ (you'd see unresolved c++ library symbols as well). So yes, the easiest solution is to use clang++ (and g++) for the C++ code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It failed to link with `clang` because `clang` is intended to be used as a C compiler.  This tradition--if you can call it that--comes from GCC, whose command-line interface `clang` follows.  If you invoke GCC as `g++` or Clang as `clang++`, it will automatically understand that it is to compile C++ code, and it will automatically link in the C++ standard library.

If you use the plain `gcc` or `clang` you can still compile C++ code, but to link it you will usually need to explicitly link the standard library (e.g. `-lc++`.  It's easier and more conventional to just use the C++ oriented name when invoking the compiler.

Comment: @EmanuelHartmann: You're welcome.  If this solved your problem, please click the checkmark on the left to "accept" this answer.